# Dominio problemas con sendmail.ini

Tags: php, mail

Cuando estaba creando una pagina web en local (servidor XAMPP) para la parte de enviar un formulario a un correo, utilizaba los archivos php.ini y sendmail.ini para poner la configuracion de mi correo. Ahora que he subido la pagina a mi dominio, no me funciona al darle enviar el formulario, pero en local si.

email.php:

```
<?php 

    $to_email = "correo@gmail.com";
    $subject =  "Cliente: " . $_POST['name'];
    $body = "Telefono: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n" . "Correo: ". $_POST['email'] . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $headers = $_POST['email'];

    mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers);

  
?>
```

AJAX:

```
function sendMailPHP() {
    $('.contact').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'php/email.php',
            data: $('.contact').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                $(".btn-general").val("ENVIADO!");
            }
        });
    });

}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="container contact" name="send_email">
                <div class="contact-inputs title">
                    <h1>Explicanos <span class="change-how">tu proyecto</span></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-inputs name" >
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos" class="form-input input-name">
                </div>
                <div class="contact-inputs email" >
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="" placeholder="Email" class="form-input input-email">
                </div>
                <div class="contact-inputs phone" >
                    <input type="number" name="phone" id="" placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-input input-phone">
                </div>
                <div class="contact-inputs message" >
                    <textarea type="radio" name="message" id="" placeholder="Mensaje" class="form-input input-message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-inputs submit" " data-aos-delay="100">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn-general btn-submit disabled-button">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Hola Victor, estas usando PHPMailer() y Gmail como cuenta de salida smtp?

Comment: ¿Revisaste en la carpeta spam? También, emite al menos un `echo` desde `email.php` y muéstralo en el `success`  para verificar que cliente y servidor se están comunicando realmente.

Comment: @A.Cedano Pensaba que si entraba en el success automaticamente me saldria el ENVIADO! en la pagina, y lo hace...por eso no entiendo porque no me llega nada

Comment: @toto No, PHPMailer() no lo utilice, es necesario?

Comment: Así es, pero es más certero probar con algo que venga del propio servidor. De paso puedes verificar si la llamada a `mail()` tuvo éxito o no con algo como `if (mail(...)) { echo "OK"; } else { echo "error"; }` así descartas si es o no un problema con la función mail() directamente. ¿Qué hay de la carpeta spam del email, la revisaste?

Comment: @A.Cedano He puesto el if como me has dicho y me sale "OK" sin problema

Comment: No me has dicho si revisaste la carpeta spam. Prueba a mandarte un email a ti mismo y revisa la carpeta spam (correo no deseado). Puede que los mensajes estén yendo a esa carpeta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tambien lo he comprobado...incluso he añadido el correo del dominio al correo que utilizaba en el local y nada...

Comment: Entonces es posible que tengas un problema en el servidor de salida (mal configurado o no configurado del todo). Sugiero que revises el archivo de log de errores, debería estar en la misma carpeta del archivo email.php, suele llamarse errorlog o parecido, si ordenas por fecha lo verás de primero porque seguro se habrá actualizado hace poco.

Comment: @A.Cedano He mirado el archivo de logs del dominio y no pone nada de nada. Me puesto en contacto para explicar mi problema al servicio de soporte del dominio porque no se cual puede ser la razon de que no funcione.

Comment: Debes mirar en la carpeta dónde está el archivo, no en el archivo de logs general, que suele estar en la carpeta public_html Casi en todos los hosting se crea un log de errores por cada carpeta donde ocurren errores. En este caso debes mirar en la carpeta `php`

Comment: @A.Cedano Me han dicho que tengo que adaptar en ese archivo PHP para que envie por SMTP, opciones que he visto son PHPMailer, pero no se como se hace...

Comment: PHPMailer es una biblioteca avanzada para enviar emails y puedes usarla si quieres, pero mail() debería funcionar para cosas simples como el ejemplo que muestras. Puede que haga falta revisar si smtp está debidamente configurado en tu `php.ini`